# meaning of "until after"

Tags: meaning

What does until after mean? For example: "The pub opens until after 6 p.m." does it mean the pub opens as the clock strikes 6 p.m. or maybe It opens after 6 p.m.? If it means that it begins to work at 6, then what is the role of "after" there and the other way around?

Comment: Your example sentence doesn't make any sense. One might say, "The pub **doesn't** open until after 6 p.m.," which technically would mean that it doesn't open at 6, but at sometime after 6. Even then, there are probably better ways to say it.

Comment: your question has been answered before https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/22389/whats-the-difference-between-until-and-until-after

Comment: Where did you see this? It looks to me like either a typo or something written by a non-native speaker. It would make more sense if it read "The pub **doesn't open** until after 6 pm."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The overall meaning of the statement will depend on whether the statement is affirmative or negative.

> We partied from 10PM until after 2AM.  <sup>stopped partying after 2AM</sup>
>
> We did not begin to party until after 2AM.<sup>began to party after 2AM</sup>
>
> The pub stays open until after 2AM.
>
> The pub does not open until after 2PM.